# How can I pass negative int to renice?

Tags: linux, libc

some bins use getopt to parse command options,like renice.  
`int getopt(int argc, char * const argv[], const char *optstring);`

```
root@m0032:/ # renice -t normal 10 6428  <br/>
root@m0032:/ # ps -p -P| grep com.spreadwin.popinfosc  <br/>
u0_a49    6428  309   658016 21800 30    10    0     0     bg  SyS_epoll_ b6cbb2e0 S com.spreadwin.popinfosc  <br/>
root@m0032:/ #  <br/>
root@m0032:/ # renice -t normal -10 6428  <br/> 
renice: invalid option -- 1  <br/>
USAGE: renice [[-r] [-t TYPE] priority pids ...] [-g pid]  <br/>
1|root@m0032:/ #   <br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

[getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html):

> The special argument ‘--’ forces in all cases the end of option scanning.

According to this, `renice -t normal -- -10 6428` should work.